# SiteMap icons not updating in Microsoft Dynamics 365 online

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to update an icon on a Dynamics 365 online SiteMap so that it differs from the icon selected for the entity found in the solution. I have tried to use the standard CRM solution SiteMap editor as well as the SiteMap editor found in the XRM Toolbox. It is a custom entity and the icon is a .png with the correct sizing.

When I try to update the icon on the sitemap the icon does not change and defaults to the icon specified for the entity in the solution. When I download the XML of the sitemap it points to the correct image (the one I want) as seen in this screenshot:

**Correct icon image in SiteMap XML,**
[image: Correct icon image in SiteMap XML]

However, if I debug the Javascript of the SiteMap we can clearly see that the source points to a different icon. This icon is the one specified for the entity in the solution:

**Debugging of Javascript of the element containing the icon**
[image: Debugging of Javascript of the element containing the icon]

**Icon as setting up for an entity in solution**
[image: Icon as setting up for an entity in solution]

Anyone have any idea or run into the same sort of problem?

Comment: Something is not right. Raise a MS ticket.

Comment: Thanks i have logged a call but wanted to see if anyone has run into this problem, will give details if/when it is resolved

Comment: i know that's very basic and obvious but sometimes we miss that these icons are cached in browser, so have you tried different browsers and hard refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its obvious but can definitely be missed. Have tried across different users and different browsers though, awaiting a response from MS.

Comment: @NDevBrad was this solved?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I'm actually not sure. I moved to a different employer before anything further became of this. Unfortunately i don't have a solid answer for this. This can be closed/archived if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve this. In the dialog called "Icon as setting up for an entity in solution" click on the Unified Interface tab. Then select your 16x16 icon. Save it and publish it. You should now see your new icon.

Comment: Unfortunately this was a long time ago and the i cant remember the solution we eventually worked with. This seems like a good feasible answer and will be marking it as a solution